# Finding spaces in many time pad

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm currently completing an online course in Cryptography, and have been give an exercise to complete. The course been running for a while and I know the answer is on the web but would like to complete it myself thought actions and research.

I have a list of 13 cipertext based on one/many time Pad - the same cipher key has been used to encrypt plain text. My task is to decrypt the last ciphertext.

The steps I have taken so far are based on cribing techniques at the following location:

- http://adamsblog.aperturelabs.com/2013/05/back-to-skule-one-pad-two-pad-me-pad.html
- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6020/many-time-pad-attack

and I'm using the following tool to XOR the ciphertexts.

In the tutorial I'm following the author suggest that the first step is to identify spaces I have tried to follow the steps but still cannot Identify the spaces once I Xor the cipher's

When I XOR the first cipertext i.e cipher 1 with cipher 2 and 3 I get the following:

> 15040900180952180C4549114F190E0159490A49120E00521201064C0A4F144F281B13490341004F480203161600000046071B1E4119061D1A411848090F4E0D0000161A0A41140C16160600151C00170B0B090653014E410D4C530F01150116000307520F104D200345020615041C541A49151744490F4C0D0015061C0A1F454F1F4509074D2F01544C080A090028061C1D002E413D004E0B141118
>
> 000D064819001E0303490A124C5615001647160C1515451A041D544D0B1D124C3F4F0252021707440D0B4C1100001E075400491E4F1F0A5211070A490B080B0A0700190D044E034F110A00001300490F054F0E08100357001E0853D4315FCEACFA7112C3E55D74AAF3394BB08F7504A8E5019C4E3E838E0F364946F31721A49AD2D24FF6775EFCB4F79FE4217A01B43CB5068BF3B52CA76543187274
>
> 000000003E010609164E0C07001F16520D4801490B09160645071950011D0341281B5253040F094C0D4F08010545050150050C1D544D061C5415044548090717074F0611454F164F1F101F411A4F430E0F0219071A0B411505034E461C1B0310454F12480D55040F18451E1B1F0A1C541646410D054C0D4C1B410F1B1B03149AD2D24FF6775EFCB4F79FE4217A01B43CB5068BF3B52CA76543187274

I'm getting confused at to where the space are based on the ASCII table which gives a 20(HEX) to the value a space.

Sorry if this is not enough information I can if more is required. Thanks Mark.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is *not* about programming. 

Comment: Disagree. It's not that much harder than those tax questions, certainly more interesting, and let's not forget that the first application of programming was cryptography. (see Turing)

Comment: @MSalters We have half a dozen near-duplicates on on crypto.se (it's based a [popular crypto course](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto)). We don't need additional duplicates on stackoverflow.

Comment: This popular crypto course have own forum where people can ask questions about tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you're linking to has the [correct answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6095/1373).

You don't appear to use that method. You should have c1⊕c2 and c1⊕c3 but your question contains three blocks of strings, one with 6 lines, one with 5 lines and one with 4 lines. That's insufficient for us to even guess what your problem is. Go back to the linked answer, read it, and follow the steps listed there.

Comment: Thanks for the direction on this guys ;-)